# jenkins pipeline options timeout and then notify

Tags: jenkins, notifications, timeout, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I have made use of

```
options {
        timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') 
    }
```

But I would like to be able to have an action on timeout eg slackNotification etc

Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use post section and `aborted` condition as your pipeline is aborted on timeout. You can add some more logic within aborted condition to only execute your action on aborts that occurred due to timeout and not due to user manual abort for example.

```
post { 
    aborted{ 
        // action on timeout
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to override the build result to unstable, in case of a timeout, but that's apparently not effective in that context.